# Convert QRCode to Image. Java

Tags: java, image

Using the following libraries:
    qrgen-1.2,    zxing-core-1.7, and 
    zxing-j2se-1.7 I generated QRCode:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(output.toString()).withSize(1000,1000).to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\QR_Code.JPG"));
    fout.write(out.toByteArray());
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
```

What I intend to do with it, is to send code to a method that accepts java.awt.Image.
How can I convert an instance of QRCode class into an instance of Image class without creating QRCode.JPG at the first place? As I see, this library doesn't provide users with methods that can carry this out, so is it possible at all? May be I can convert stream to Image?

Comment: I don't know those libraries, but try this: `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));`  (`BufferedImage` is a sublclass of `Image`, assuming you're talking about `java.awt.image.Image`)

Comment: Mistyped and can't edit for some reason - that should be `java.awt.Image`, not `java.awt.image.Image`

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the qr code to a byte array output stream then use byte array in the stream to create a `BufferedImage`.

```
import net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public static BufferedImage generate() {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        QRCode.from("http://www.stackoverflow.com").writeTo(baos);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        return ImageIO.read(bais);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```